# Search multiple tables ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, lucene, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented as search function on my website that uses 1 table using the following function.

Search function

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Results(string SearchString)
        {
            using (var objCtx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var Restaurant = from u in objCtx.Restaurants
                           select u;


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
                {
                    Restaurant = Restaurant.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchString));
                }

                return View(Restaurant.ToList());
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to extend this function so that it can search through multiple tables without using a search engine such as Lucene.net?

Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the tables then merge the iqueryable lists

```
var Restaurant = from u in objCtx.Restaurants
                       select u;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
{
    Restaurant = Restaurant.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchString));
}

// Second table.
var Restaurant2 = from u in objCtx.Restaurants2
                       select u;


if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
{
    Restaurant2 = Restaurant2.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(SearchString));
}

return View(Restaurant.Union(Restaurant2).ToList());
```

or

```
return View(Restaurant.Concat(Restaurant2).ToList());
```